# Has anyone seen https suddenly stop working?

Tags: nginx, tcp, https

My webserver has been working for years. It suddenly stopped working today -- in https. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.5 and serving pages through nginx.

When I receive an http request on port 80, it shows up in the access logs and is handled correctly. When I receive an https request on port 443, it never shows up in the nginx logs and never gets forwarded on to my django webserver.

I can telnet to port 80 but get timeouts on 443. (I never tried that before, so I don't know if it's new.)

My ports are open properly.

```
 ~ $ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1285/nginx      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1285/nginx      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1285/nginx
```

Could it be related to tcp vs tcp6? Only plain tcp is on 443, but they're both on 80. If so, how would I change that? And what would cause a sudden change?

I'm not running a firewall. I double checked, and ufw status is inactive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Visit https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to test your server.  It provides detailed report, perhaps something will show up for you to investigate further.

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't assess my server, because it can't connect to it on 443.  It tells me: `Assessment failed: Unable to connect to the server`

Comment: I checked my staging server (where https does still work). I only have tcp6 on port 80, not on 443, so it's just like above. I can telnet to either 80 or 443 there. I really think it's as if someone has forced a port closed, though the server seems to think it's open.

Comment: I only know things on Windows.   There are on a few things that relates to a port.  A servicing listening to a port, firewall not blocking the port and a site is properly bound to the port (in IIS server for example).  If you can do Telnet and not https, you should check if the site is properly bound to port 443 for https.

Comment: Can you access port 443 from same host?

Answer (score 0):

A I solved it. All my servers are in the AWS cloud, and I have a security group that says only specified IPs are allowed to ssh in. When I added a new IP that could ssh in, I accidentally deleted the row that said anyone could connect via https on 443. Sigh.